# How to delete taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I would like to delete taxonomy term. Unfortunately on taxonomy -> list I can only see "edit" button next to each term (under "operations"):

[image]

How can I delete the term I added earlier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click "edit":
[image] Drupal will take you to the page where you can delete that term; right beside the "save" button:
[image] For bulk deletion you may take a look at the [taxonomy manager module](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following module to delete taxonomy terms.

https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_multidelete_terms